# How Do I increment date on every iteration

Tags: python, odoo

what I am trying to achieve is to predict payment date depending on the payment frequency that is selected. for instance when a user select a payment frequency of monthly, the system should be able to predict the payment date for 12 months, the first payment date should be the date_start and then increment by 30 to predict the next payment date. here is my code.

```
def action_compute_amortization(self):
        """This automatically create the installment the employee need to pay to
        company based on payment start date and the no of installments.
            """
        for rec in self:
            rec.amortization_lines.unlink()
            date_start = rec.date_from
            days_in_a_year = rec.coverage_term
            payment_freq = rec.premium_frequency
            frequency : dict = {
                'monthly':round(days_in_a_year/30),
                'quarterly': round(days_in_a_year/90),
                'biannually': round(days_in_a_year/182),
                'yearly': round(days_in_a_year/days_in_a_year)
            }
            term = frequency.get(payment_freq,days_in_a_year)
            amount = rec.policy_risk_ids.cover_ids.premium_currency
            for i in range(1,days_in_a_year + 1):
                while term > 0:
                    payment_date = date_start
                    if payment_freq == "monthly":
                        payment_date = date_utils.add(date_start, days=30)
                    elif payment_freq == "quarterly":
                        payment_date = date_utils.add(date_start, days=90)
                    elif payment_freq == "biannually":
                        payment_date = date_utils.add(date_start, days=182)
                    elif payment_freq == "yearly":
                        payment_date = date_start
                    else:
                        payment_date = date_utils.add(date_start, hours=24)
                    self.env['epgi.policy.amortization'].create({
                        'payment_date': payment_date,
                        'amount': amount,
                        'insured_id': rec.insured_id.id,
                        'policy_id': rec.id})
                    term -= 1
        return True
```

but I am not getting the desired result, as I am only getting the immediate next payment date. but I need the date_start to be the payment date of the first installment, then the next payment date if monthly should increment the old date by 30 days and so on.

I would appreciate all the help.

Comment: Do you mean same date every month, or every 30 days ?

Comment: depends on the chosen payment frequency, if monthly, every 30 days, if quarterly , every 90 days, if bi-annually every 182 days and so on

Comment: So you could have Jan 1st, Jan 31, Mar 2...

Answer (score 0):

I have some problem of the parameter meaning in your code.
So i implement a simple instance show you ,hope it can help you.
Follow is my code,it will calculate and record all payment_date in 365 days,the value of deadDays  can be specified arbitrarily

```
import  datetime
import math
from decimal import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(datetime.date.today())

    # the user input payment_freq , modify this
    payment_freq = "monthly"

    # the user input total amount , modify this
    totalAmount = Decimal.from_float(1000)

    payment_cycle = 0
    if payment_freq == "monthly":
        payment_cycle = 30
    elif payment_freq == "quarterly":
        payment_cycle = 90
    elif payment_freq == "biannually":
        payment_cycle = 182
    elif payment_freq == "yearly":
        payment_cycle = 365
    else:
        payment_cycle = 1

    deadDays = 365
    cycle = round(deadDays / payment_cycle)
    i = 0
    # transfer the payment_date from a dateTime to a list of dateTime
    payment_date  = []
    tempTime = datetime.date.today()

    for i in range (0 ,cycle):
        tempTime = tempTime +datetime.timedelta(days=30)
        payment_date .append(tempTime)
    divideAmount = math.ceil(totalAmount *100/Decimal.from_float(cycle))/100

    # the result , i print it ,you can use your function  deal with  those value
    print(payment_date)
    print(divideAmount)
```

Comment: there are 5 payment_freq namely; daily, monthly, quarterly, biannually and yearly. hence i have an else block that should increment by 24hrs or daily.  the whole picture is that a user should see date of payments for what ever payment frequency they choose, if they choose quarterly  for instance the term will be 4, that means the system should show the amount and due dates for them to make payments 4 times in a year, if monthly 12 times, if biannually 2 times in a year, if daily 365 days in a year, if yearly the date start.

Comment: In my code ,the payment_date has the all date  ,you can copy the code and run code to see it print .If the amount you pay each time is average, then you only need to use the total amount  minus  the number of dates

Comment: your code do print out a list of all the payment dates. but that is not what i need. the increment should only occur on every iteration of term and written to the field. term is same as cycle in your code. the payment_date field only takes a single datetime value.  on the ui the payment frequency  and amount shows correctly, 4 frequencies for quartely, 12 for monthly and so on. my problem is the payment dates, with my code it prediction is not correct